# [PostgreSQL / plpgsql ]: How to use function parameter inside DECLARE block?

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Test_Param_Insert_Data(p_schema_table text, p_dblinkcon text) RETURNS void AS $$
declare 
    rec p_schema_table;
BEGIN
....
```

How to use function parameter **p_schema_table** as **composite_type_name** e.g. **rec public.customer**.

I tested create function, but error return

> ERROR:  type "p_schema_table" does not exist

Why plpgsql language don't understand **p_schema_table** is passing function parameter, It's should treat to table name e.g **public.customer**

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare variable, which type is passed as parameter. In such case you should declare it using RECORD type.

Comment: I already try to use RECORD type, but it does't work for me. I want to wildcard (*) all elements of **rec** e.g. `INSERT INTO public.customer_test SELECT rec.*;`